# Spring docker volume and autoreload

Tags: java, spring, docker

I m actually wanting to use docker containers to develop with java.

I m actually having a "good" image, using phusion/baseimage and JAVA 8, gradle and git inside of it.

Actually, this works well and I can connect through SSH.

With volume, I can work in a container directory from my real host.

I wanted to know if I can launch the tomcat server embedded in the SpringBoot, from the container, directly from IntelliJ for example ?

So I can restart / reload it easily, without having to open an ssh prompt, gradle build with command line at each modifications etc...

Comment: I haven't tried something like what you discussing, but may I ask why you would want to do your regular development inside a Docker container? Why not just develop like usual in your default environment (where your IDE can reload changes etc.)  and perform automated and/or manual tests on periodically created artifacts that run inside Docker?

Comment: In need to have the same environnment for development and production. Actually, I m developping using Windows, and my production server is Debian based. I faced some behaviour problems in the past, due to the difference of these OS. Spring is maybe not the best image for comparison (my tests were under NodeJS, with Node Modules)

Comment: if you want to also start tomcat in your container, you will need a tool to deal with it, like supervisor http://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/ You have other tools like runit, s6, daemontools... Docker is supposed to launch one process in a container, if you want more than one, you will need such a tool.

Comment: @Skahrz I see your point! But it seems to me that development inside a Docker container seriously impedes productivity.